# jQuery slidedown and then fadein content

Tags: jquery, fadein, slide, jquery-hover

I wonder if anyone can help, I'm trying to replicate a menu (in principle) that a client likes on: http://www.arup.com

So far I have tried looking at the code/jquery behind the site and it seems to be over complicated (for me at least), I have got this far on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2ySU/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#qc1,#qc2,#qc3').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.answer').stop(true, true).fadeIn({
            duration: '3000',
            queue: true
        }).css('display', 'none').slideDown({
            duration: '1000',
            queue: false
        });
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.answer').stop(true, true).fadeOut({
            duration: '3000',
            queue: true
        }).slideUp({
            duration: '2000',
            queue: false
        });
    });
});
```

Ideally I would like the div to slide down, and THEN for the content to fade in onmousein (and then the reverse onmouseout) but have tried for hours as a jQuery newbie.

Comment: Consider doing it using css3 http://jsfiddle.net/3WfaK/2/

Comment: Why would you make people hover a blank space to see the text? This is horrible user experience and will seem slow. What you got now looks good now

Comment: @Huangism I think you misunderstood the OP... Look at the example site

Comment: Oh I see it, basically slidedown the container then fade in content

Comment: Are any of our solutions helpful, or are you looking for something else? I'm interested to see the final solution to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/LLE4J/1/) perhaps?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".answer").each(function() {
      $(this).hide();
  });
  $('#qc1,#qc2,#qc3').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).find('.answer')
        .stop(1,1)
        .slideDown(500, function() {
          // note: i've wrapped the dropdown's content with an additional div.
          $(this).find("div").fadeIn(500); 
        });
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.answer div')
        .stop(1,1)
        .fadeOut(500, function() {
          $(this).parent('.answer').stop().slideUp(500);
        });
      }
  );
});
```

Essentially, I'm fadeIn()ing the dropdown's *content* through a callback, once the slideDown() of it's *parent* has finished, and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help Thykka, I think the first one almost nailed it though. Cheers Matt

Answer (score 0):

Something I would refer you to is the [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) documentation specifically for [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), and [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) functions.

There is the option to have a "complete" function that executes after the animation completes. That is what you're looking for to execute the fade AFTER the slide and vise versa.

As in thykka's solutoin, another div was required for the fade and slide to happen seperately.

```
<div class="answer" id="a1">
    <div class="answer_content">
        What makes us different
        <br />Vision & Values
        <br />Our Story
        <br />Our People
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/3WfaK/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var qcContainer = $('#qc1,#qc2,#qc3');

    qcContainer.hover(
    // On mouse enter function
    function () {
        qcContainer.find('.answer').stop(true, true).slideDown(
            "slow", function () {
            // slideDown is complete, now for fadeIn
            qcContainer.find('.answer_content').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow', function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });

    },
    // On mouse leave function
    function () {
        qcContainer.find('.answer_content').stop(true, true).fadeOut(
            "slow", function () {
            // fadeOut complete, time for slideUp
            qcContainer.find('.answer').stop(true, true).slideUp("slow", function () {
                // Animation complete.
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, that's almost perfect, all I need to do is wrap it in a container as per Huangism's answer below and that will be spot on! Cheers Matt

Answer (score 0):

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/P2ySU/3/ This is what I saw on the example website. All it's doing is expanding the container and having it stay that way when the menu is in action

```
$('#container').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '200px'});
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).animate({height: '53px'});
    }
});
```

I added

```
<div id="container">
```

as an overall wrapper. Also you should change the duplicate ID on the items and use class instead

Comment: Thanks for your help Huangism, i'm going to borrow your suggestion to wrap it up in a container but using Jonathan's code above! Cheers Matt